# Migrate OpenGL ES1 to ES2

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

When doing the update cocos2d 1.0 for the cocos2d 2.0 my program ceases to work because the coscos2d 2.0 uses OpenGL ES2 instead of OpenGL ES1.

Is there any method of classes created by me continuing to use OpenGL ES1?

If necessary make a migration there any quick way or do I have to rewrite all the code?

Comment: Did you write or use any 3rd party class that performs any OpenGL operations? If so you'll have to convert that code to GL ES 2.0. If not, you need to provide more information and be more specific about "ceases to work".

Comment: ... and, for the record, Apple's GLKit contains a bunch of stuff to make the transition easy. But exactly what further detail to add to this comment to turn it into an answer depends upon the specifics as asked for by LearnCocos2D.

Comment: There are some classes that utilize OpenGL (three classes). When I say "ceases to work" is because the program does not compile with code errors, because the classes used are not recognized in OpenGL ES2

Answer (score 0):

You should look over the migration to v2.0 guide on the Cocos2D website (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:migrate_to_v2.0).  Should be able to guide you through most situations you'll run into.